# Having trouble making an XSD file work appropriately

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I have this xml file and i need to create a xsd file that validates that all the data is there and write the code that will validate the xml against the xsd file. The output will display “Valid”  if there are no errors. The output will display “Not valid” if there are errors and the output would also display the errors.

```
<Student gradYear="2014"> <!--GraduationYear is required-->
 <FirstName>
     John
 </FirstName><!--FirstName is required-->
<LastName>
    Smith
</LastName><!--LastName is required-->
 <SocialSecurity>
123-45-6789
 </SocialSecurity><!--SocialSecurity is required and must be in the format shown-->
 <Phone type="Home"> <!--HomePhone  is required and must match the format shown-->
        <Number>
    724-555-5454
    </Number>
 </Phone>
 <PhoneNumber type="Cell"> <!--Cell Phone is optional, but must be in the correct format if used-->
        <Number>
    724-555-5858
    </Number>
 </PhoneNumber>
</Student>
```

I have a xsd file that displays if it is valid or not but that doesn't include making the required fields required or checking the format.  It only is capable of checking to make sure the xml file contains all of the elements.

Comment: So your question is, how to set required field in XSD ?

Comment: You would use "use="required"" in the attribute field, but you can't do that for simpletypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSD will validate both the mandatory and formats, however the error that would be displayed would depend on what is doing the validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Student">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FirstName">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:minLength value="1" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="LastName">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:minLength value="1" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="SocialSecurity">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Phone">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Number">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:enumeration value="Home" />
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PhoneNumber">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Number">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:enumeration value="Cell" />
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="gradYear" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```